# Basic node childprocess returns alwasy an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, unexpected-token

master.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');  
const child_process = require('child_process');  
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {  
  var workerProcess = child_process.spawn('node', ['support.js']);  
  workerProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {  
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);  
  });  
  workerProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {  
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);  
  });  
  workerProcess.on('close', function (code) {  
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);  
  });  
}
```

support.js:

```
console.log("Child Process " + process.argv[2] + " executed." );
```

Every time I run my master process in the console (cmd: node master.js), it returns following error 3 times:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1070:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1120:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47

stderr: C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\testing\support.js:1
��c
```

And I have absolutely no idea why.

### Solution:

I had a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in my support.js file, as indicated by the question mark symbols (�) in the error message.

You can check your own files for [byte order marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) with following [tool](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/#validate-by-upload+)

Comment: I see you're on Windows. You may have a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or something else at the beginning fo the file that Node isn't expecting.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the support file and rewrote it from scratch, and now it's working.

Comment: When writing a question, you should look back at your post and see if at least one sentence ends with a question mark.